# Is there any logic behind Dropbox synchronization?

Tags: download, logic, dropbox

When you sync your PC with your Dropbox account, it starts downloading the files, but not alphabetically, not starting with biggest or smallest files first.

Is there any logic behind the download process or is it just randomly downloading?

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox (and other sync apps) use something called an [FSEventStream](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/UsingtheFSEventsFramework/UsingtheFSEventsFramework.html) (OS-X) that tells the operating system to notify the Dropbox application each time a file is added/modified/deleted and then initiates the sync routine on the changed file or folder. It happens in ascending order of the file creation or modification timestamp. It also downloads the files in this order.